# Number of degree $k$ functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, computational-complexity, boolean-algebras, enumerative-combinatorics

Given a Boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}$, there is a real multivariate multilinear polynomial that is associated with in through interpolation.

Example: $AND(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n)$ is associated with $\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$.

Degree of Boolean function is least possible total degree of real multivariate multilinear polynomial associated with it.

How many degree $k$ Boolean functions are there with $n$ variables out of total $2^{2^n}$ functions?

Is there an inductive procedure?

Comment: How many degree $\le k$ multilinear monomials in $n$ variables are there? This is trivial combinatorics.

Comment: Or are you talking about a different field than $\mathbb F_2$, by any chance? Then you need to make that explicit in the question.

Comment: I am talking about reals.

Comment: This is elementary linear algebra.  Why are you asking this on a research mathematics site?

Comment: I am getting not much help here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103587/number-of-degree-k-functions?

Comment: I don’t think it’s easy over the reals, and there likely isn’t any decent exact expression except for a few special cases. Though it’s easy to see that all but a tiny fraction ($\approx2^{-n/2}$) of all functions have degree $n$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek $(1)$ How did you get count $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$? $(2)$ Is there a linear algebra technique as mentioned in a comment above?

Comment: (1) Not $2^{n/2}$, but a $2^{-n/2}$ fraction. More precisely, the number of functions of degree $< n$ is $\binom{2^n}{2^{n-1}}$ because of http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/27048 . (2) As I already wrote, I’m skeptical. We are talking an intersection of a linear space with a discrete set.